# How to display createelement (error) message in a JS Form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to display a error message when the value username is incorrect. but is not working

```js
function handleInvalidities(input) { // Takes input field as parameter
    let errMsg = "";
    if (input.validity.valueMissing) {
        errMsg = "Invalid entry. This field can not be blank. Please enter a value."; // Check for missing fields

        return errMsg;
    }

    function validateForm(errMsg) {
        let name = document.getElementById('userName');
        if (name == null || name == "") {
            let errElem = document.createElement("span");
            errElem.setAttribute("class", "error");
            let errText = document.createTextNode(errMsg);
            errElem.appendChild(errText);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
function validateForm() {
    let errorMsg =
        " Invalid entry. This field can not be blank. Please enter a value.";
    let name = document.getElementById("userName");
    if (name.value === "") {
        let errElem = document.createElement("span");
        errElem.setAttribute("class", "error");
        errElem.textContent = errorMsg;
        name.after(errElem);
    }
}
```

```html
 <input name="username" id="userName">
 <button type="button" onclick="validateForm()">Validate</button>
```

Comment: the div wasn't supposed to be a span since createElement(span) is being used? if I create a element span with a class of error.

Comment: If you don’t want the extra div , then you have to select the input and append the span after it.

Comment: Something like, name.appendAfter(errElem).

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried this and msg still doesn't show. Now the register button is not submitting to another page.

Answer (score 0):

if value is blank add text to span with the id="error" in html

```
if (input !== "") {
        // if value isn't blank do this
    }
else{
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Invalid entry. This field can not be blank. Please enter a value."; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="error"></span>
```

alternative which also creates the span in javascript:

```
if (input !== "") {
        // if value isn't blank do this
    }
else{
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "Invalid entry. This field can not be blank. Please enter a value.";
    const att = document.createAttribute("class");      
    att.value = "error";
    span.setAttributeNode(att);        
    document.body.appendChild(span);               // Append <span> to <body> 
}
```

Comment: I used the alert msg before just to check if the code was working.. but I want to create in javascript a span with a class of error do display the message when the value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

As you tried, a "generic" function can be used in order to check the validity of any input value with `handleInvalidities(inputValue)`
Then a function `validateField(elementId)` to apply the above validation and print the error itself. Then the `onSubmit` function where you can call the validate field for any input field from your form

EDIT

Yes, it is possible, I created a div with all specifications (I tried with span but didn't succeed :( ) and for each element the error div will be appended, the elements structure will be

```
<div>
   <input/>
   <errorDiv/>
</div>
```

If you write the text in input and press submit, the error will disappear. xD

```js
function handleInvalidities(inputValue) { // Takes input field as parameter
  if (inputValue == null || inputValue == "") {
    return "Invalid entry. This field can not be blank. Please enter a value.";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

function createErrorDivforElement(elementId, message) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.width = "auto";
  div.style.height = "18px";
  div.classList.add("error");
  div.innerHTML = message;
  div.id = elementId + "_error";

  return div;
}

function validateField(elementId) {
  const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  const elementValue = element.value;

  const error = handleInvalidities(elementValue)
  const errorDiv = createErrorDivforElement(elementId, error);

// if it's = 2, it already has the error div attached
  if (element.parentNode.childNodes.length < 2) { 
    element.parentNode.appendChild(errorDiv);
  }

  var errDiv = document.getElementById(elementId + "_error");
  if (error !== "") {
    errDiv.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    errDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function onSubmit() {
  validateField("userName");
  validateField("country");
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" id="userName" aria-describedby="name-format" placeholder="Name"></div>

<div><input type="text" id="country" aria-describedby="name-format" placeholder="Country"></div>

<button type="submit" value="submit" onclick="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I undestand thx. but there's any other way of doing the same thing without touching the HTML? via Dom javascript? I Just want to create in javascript a span with a class of error to display the message when is empty.